# Storing associative array into database

Tags: php, mysql, performance, blob

I have 3 tables:

1- questions
2- answers
3- user_answers

```
    questions
_________________
| id | question |
|____|__________|
| 1  |   1+1    |
|____|__________|



    answers
_________________
| id |  answer  |  
|____|__________|
| 1  |    1     | 
|____|__________|
| 2  |    3     |
|____|__________|
| 3  |    2     | 
|____|__________|

                 user_answers
______________________________________________
| id |  answer_id  |  question_id |   user_id |
|____|_____________|______________|___________|
| 1  |    1        |       1      |      1    |
|____|_____________|______________|___________|
| 2  |    3        |       2      |      1    |
|____|_____________|______________|___________|
| 3  |    2        |       3      |      1    |
|____|_____________|______________|___________|
```

So as you see there is many to many relation within `user_answers` table.

Instead of saving each question with its answer in a row, I want to save all questions and answers as an array. So there will be 1 row for each user for performance.

I searched about that and found `serialize()` function and that the datatype for that column should be `Blob`.

So the new table would be like this:

```
        user_answers
______________________________
|  id  |  array  |  user_id  |
|______|_________|___________|
|   1  |   Blob  |     1     |
|______|_________|___________|
```

The array could be like that:

```
$array = array(
    1 =>  1,
    2 =>  3,
    3 =>  2
);
```

There could be like 20s or more questions.

Is that's the best way for doing this? or saving each question in a row? or using another datatype for the `array` column?

Comment: The way it was is the best way. See: [Database normalization](https://blog.saleslayer.com/why-is-database-normalization-so-important). What if you want to check only the answers to question 14?

Comment: "_for performance_" What are the performance benefits, have you done some testing? How about if you want to find out user#1's answer on question#2?

Comment: If I want to get a specific question, I would fetch the whole row and get that one. I would get 1 row like the 1st way too

Comment: @brombeer I haven't done any testing. But I thought this would be better than saving like 20 rows for each user

Comment: I think you think that creating so many rows, one for each user-question conbination, must be bad for performance, but it is not. Databases were made to handle vast quantities of data. Having to retrieve more data than is really needed, then having to process it, before it can be use, _is_ bad for performance.

Comment: And if you *really* want to denormalize, you should use a simple format like `1;3;2` instead of a PHP-specific serialization format.

Comment: Serialize is a good way to store array into database. Another one is json, that not depends on PHP. But, as many has said, in your case I would prefer to have a table for the relationship user_answers.

Answer (score 0):

> 1 row for each user for performance

That may backfire.

If you pack a bunch of stuff together via serialization, JSON, etc, you need to avoid looking into the stuff.  That is, the only practical and efficient thing to do is fetch the entire string into your application and break it apart there.

If you might need to, say, fetch "what every user gave as an answer just for question 3, then the `question number` needs to be its own column.